# How to add matlab to favorites bar?

Tags: matlab, favorites

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu. I installed matlab and I am able to open it from the terminal by doing:

```
cd ~/Matlab_R2023b/bin
./matlab
```

Is there a way to add a matlab shortcut to the favorites bar?

[image]